# std::less compiling issue

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to use a user defined class 'A' with the template std::less. I have also a function overriding `<` operator as required by `std::less`. This code is not compiling.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<functional>
using namespace std;
class A{
public:
        A(int x=0):a(x){}
        int a;
        bool operator<(const A& ref){
                return a<ref.a;
        }
};
int main()
{
        A a1(1);
        A a2(2);
        std::less<A> comp;
        if( comp(a1,a2)){
                cout<<"less"<<endl;
        }
        else{
                cout<<"more"<<endl;
        }

}
```

Comment: What is the compiler error? I am guessing you need to make your comparison operator `const`: `bool operator<(const A& ref) const { ...}`.

Comment: [`const`-correctness](http://ideone.com/8KWZ6V)

Comment: If it doesn't compile, then the actual compiler error *might* probably be of large help in the search for a solution to the problem, if not for you then at least for the ones reading your question. Sorry, but a simple upvote of *juanchopanza*'s comment is just not enough to clarify this.

Answer (score 11):

Make it

```
    bool operator<(const A& ref) const{
            return a<ref.a;
    }
```